# Am I misunderstanding 'min'?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have:

```
array1 = [[0, 0], [2, 1]]
array2 = [[1, 0], [3, 1]]
```

I believe this should be the case:

```
array1[1][0] == [0, 2]
array2[1][0] == [0, 3]
```

Following this, why is it that the following code,

```
[array1[1][0], array2[1][0]].min # => 2
```

returns `2`?

How is it that `2` is the minimum out of two-dimensional arrays in which there are three instances of `0` and three instances of `1`?

Am I misunderstanding the `min` function, or am I misunderstanding what is going on when I use the two-dimensional arrays?

Comment: _"I believe this should be the case [...]"_ – to validate your assumptions, launch [irb](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html), enter `array1 = [[0, 0], [2, 1]]` and then `array1[1][0]`.

Comment: Who edited my god damn post without my permission?

Comment: Quoting Help Center > Privileges > [Edit Questions And Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit): _"We believe in the power of community editing. That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit **anything** in the system without it going through peer review. Not just your posts – **anyone's posts!**"_

Answer (score 3):

When `[1][0]` call for the first array you take the second array from it `[2, 1]` and then take the first number from taken array `2`.

```
array1[1][0] => 2
array2[1][0] => 3
[2, 3].min => 2
```

Comment: Wait. So you are saying that the first set of brackets represents [0, 0] and [2, 1], whereas the second set of brackets is either going to be 0, 0, 2, or 1?
So if I call array1[1][1], I am looking at [0,0], and calling the second zero from that array within the array?

Therefore does it stand to reason that the format generally reads:
arrayofarraysname[arraywithinarray][elementofarray]?

Comment: @AaronGodhard `[]` is a method call which returns an object. If the receiver happens to be an array, then the return value is the object at the given index (zero-based), so `array1[1]` returns the 2nd element. If that element is also an array, then `array1[1][1]` will returns its 2nd element. You could also write: `subarray = array[1]` and call `subarray[1]` afterwards. Same result.

Comment: @stefan Your answer perfectly paraphrases my question - thank you :).
So basically I was thinking in the wrong terms here; I'm not calling BOTH subarrays, I am calling ONE subarray.

Answer (score 1):

It goes like:

```
array1[1][0] == [2, 1][0] == 2
array2[1][0] == [3, 1][0] == 3
[array1[1][0], array2[1][0]].min == [2, 3].min # => 2
```

Under your counterfactual assumption:

```
array1[1][0] == [0, 2]
array2[1][0] == [0, 3]
```

the comparison should be:

```
[array1[1][0], array2[1][0]].min == [[0, 2], [0, 3]].min # => [0, 2]
```